Is Fuzzy Grouping Discontinued in Power BI? Seeking Alternatives
I'm dealing with a dataset containing over 200,000 rows of data and noticed that Power BI lacks the "fuzzy grouping" function. I'm uncertain if this feature has been discontinued. My challenge lies in reconciling variations in customer account names example Cartrack, CARTRACK PTY LTD, CarTrack (PTY) Ltd, etc. While I can address this manually for each account, the sheer volume of data makes this approach impractical. I've attempted to implement fuzzy grouping in Power Query for individual account names, but I'm unsure how to extend this solution to handle multiple accounts simultaneously. Fuzzy grouping has been instrumental in resolving similar issues in the past, and I'm seeking guidance on alternative approaches to achieve similar results efficiently.

Fuzzy grouping is there but you need to write the M manually. It is not available via the UI. You can reference here for the syntax: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-fuzzygroup

Ahh thanks, I can also confirm it is on the cloud service :) Just found it now. Thank you for taking the time to assist me with another alternative!
